# what is the meaning of "sw" in libswscale of ffmpeg?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

In FFMpeg, we always say hello to libswscale and libswresample, but, what is the meaning of sw in libswscale and libswresample?

Comment: **S**oft**W**are

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sw is short for software, and it implies that the functionality is performed by the general purpose CPU as opposed to a dedicated device such as an extension card.